# check given site is a subsite or root site csom powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

How to check given site is a sub site or site collection in csom powershell

Thanks

swetha

Comment: check if parent web is null

Comment: I have checked as parentweb.Title -eq $null.It worked.Thanks for the solution.